# How to remove JQuery's Ui-Datepicker-Year select arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery's ui-date-picker and have modified the css.
I am having trouble removing the arrows from beside the year. I just want to be able to click on the year then the drop down shows and lets me select the year. How can I go from

This

[image: Dropdown with arrows]

To This

[image: Dropdown without arrows]

I know I am able to select the year with .ui-datepicker-year and have tried accessing the element that comes after but I am not able to target the arrows...and turn off the display.

Comment: 'select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
select{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks anyway

```
select::-ms-expand {display: none; }
select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```